# swift 3.1.1.-release on linux copyItem(atPath:toPath:) is not yet implemented

Tags: swift, linux, docker, containers

I'm using the swift ubuntu docker: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker

and try to copy a file from pathA to pathB. During the execution I get the fatal error:

```
fatal error: copyItem(atPath:toPath:) is not yet implemented: file Foundation/NSFileManager.swift, line 376
Illegal instruction
```

The command:

```
# swift --version
```

responses

```
Swift version 3.1.1 (swift-3.1.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Online I found the information that it should be implemented:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2639

Can someone help out? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently it isn't implemented on the Swift 3.1 branch for Linux: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/swift-3.1-branch/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L375.

Comment: Oh yes - "NSUnimplemented()" ... Is there a easy workaround to copy a picture for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyItem(atPath:toPath:)` is not implemented on the [Swift 3.1 branch](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/swift-3.1-branch/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L375) 
of the Foundation framework for Linux:

```
open func copyItem(atPath srcPath: String, toPath dstPath: String) throws {
    NSUnimplemented()
}
```

What you can for example do is

```
let fm = FileManager.default
if let contents = fm.contents(atPath: srcPath) {
    if !fm.createFile(atPath: destPath, contents: contents, attributes: nil) {
        print("cannot write destination file")
    }
} else {
    print("cannot read source file")
}
```

which is a simplified version of how `copyItem(atPath:toPath:)`
is implemented on the [master branch](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/FileManager.swift#L374).

If the file is very large then you may want to copy in chunks
instead of reading the entire file into memory, for example like this:

```
guard let srcFile = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: srcPath) else {
    fatalError("cannot open source file")
}
guard let destFile = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: destPath) else {
    fatalError("cannot open destination file")
}
while case let data = srcFile.readData(ofLength: 1024 * 1024), data.count > 0 {
    destFile.write(data)
}
srcFile.closeFile()
destFile.closeFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that works fine. I found in the meanwhile another solution which also works ;-)

```
let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path))
guard FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: url.path, contents: data, attributes: nil) else {
    print("Can not read/create the file")
    return false
}
```